# preventing image resize when displayed on page

Tags: javascript, css

so i have this image with a specific size and when i display the image it increases in size. How can i prevent image resizing when displaying it.?

This is my line for displaying the image

```
 <img class="imagedisplay" data-bind="attr: { src: ThumbnailUrl, alt: Title }" src="" />
```

Is there a way in which i could control it to display exactly as its original size without alterations via css or javascript? I am not sure what my options are to do this.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Re: `data-bind=...` Is this some client-side MVC framework? Not tagged?

Comment: what's changing your image's size? is it the container? or js or what?

Comment: .imagedisplay {height:auto;width:auto;} you may use a higher selector or use !important for test :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image doesn't change size on it's own. If nothing affects it, it will display at it's native height and width. If it's changing, then either it's width has been set via CSS to a % of it's parent, or it's being affected by Javascript. To make it stay the same, you need to turn off whatever is changing it. If you post your full code, we can help more specifically.

Comment: Thanks, i found that in another css class the width was being set to 100% which was causing the increase in image size. I took it out and it is displaying properly.